# Programatically update non-wordpress repository hosted (self-hosted) plugins

Tags: plugins, updates

I am working on a plugin that checks for and updates other plugins. The new plugin can easily update other plugins which are hosted on wordpress repository. But how can the new plugin update other plugins that are not hosted in wordpress repository(i.e. self hosted)?

So basically, is there any officially prescribed, standard setting/info inside a WP plugin to indicate the location of where to check for future updates?

Vishnu N

Comment: As far I know, there is not a standard way to support remote updates in self-hosted plugins. [It's not like joomla that has an API for remote installs/updates](https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server); in WordPress, each developer who has self-hosted plugins/themes handle the remote install/updates on his/her own way, [for example on this way](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181).

Comment: @cybmeta Ok. that confirms what I thought. Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen: https://github.com/afragen/github-updater ? I use this for custom client theme/plugins hosted on github or bitbucket.